# How to access /data/ without rooting bu from a platform signed app?

Tags: android, boot-animation

Hi I'm working on a custom application on my own custom ROM and I need to be able to programmatically change the boot animation from the code.

I wanted to do this by copying bootanimation.zip to /data/local within the application but can't access that location despite my application being signed with the PLATFORM KEY.

The platform key signature does give a lot of extra freedom but unfortunately doesn't seem to get around these types of permission problems. Any way around that?

NOTE: The constraints are

- I can't / don't want to root the ROM
- I don't have a chance to recompile the ROM to grant exceptions or to set different permissions (that would be the obvious solution to this!)
- No USB/ADB access unfortunately. This needs to happen within my PLATFOR-SIGNED application
- No third-parties app. Only my platform key signed app which can include any code I want.

Any ideas within the constraints above?

Thanks!